# Como remover essa margem com bootstrap ? ja usei o m-0 mas não funciona

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Como posso remover essa borda a direita na div das imagens e na div do container ?
estou utilizando o bootstrap 4.6, ja tentei utilizar o m-0, porém aplica a todo conteudo, menos na margem da direita, e mesmo no inspecionar elemento mostra que não tem margem a direita.
preciso ocupar todo o espaço da div com as imagens, são imagens diferentes, utilizei essas so para representar.

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>


<body> 
<div class="container m-0"> <!-- Inicio Div escolas -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        <img class="" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">  
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        
                        <img class="" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        
                       <img class="" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        
                       <img class="" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        
                         <img class="" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            
            

        </div>

    </div> <!-- Fim Div escolas -->
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Quer ocupar 100% da largura é isso?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>


<body> 
<div class="container m-0"> <!-- Inicio Div escolas -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        <img class="w-100"src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 m-0 p-0 " style="border:1px solid red;">  
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        
                        <img class="w-100" style="width: 100%" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        
                       <img class="w-100" style="width: 100%" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        
                       <img class="w-100" style="width: 100%" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 m-0 p-0" style="border:1px solid red;">
                <a href="#">
                    <span>
                        
                         <img class="w-100" style="width: 100%" src="https://www.pportodosmuseus.pt/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/plaka_porto-300x197.jpg" alt=""> 
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
            
        </div>

    </div> <!-- Fim Div escolas -->
 </body>
</html>
```